# What is a minimum sample size for a paired t-test and what is a non-parametric equivalent if data is non-normal?

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, sample-size, t-test, statistical-power

I have 4 sample pairs, let's say (x1, y1),...,(x4, y4).

- What is the minimum sample size for a paired t-test?
- Which assumption should I check for paired t-test?
- If my data is non-normal, what is an alternative non-parametric test?

Comment: You will have very small power with only 4 pairs unless the effect size is huge (for example, if $x_i$ is the weight of a butterfly and $y_i$ is the weight of the tree you found it on).

Comment: great example! I will use it in my consulting now :-)

Comment: @shabby Because effect size depends on a *standard deviation* of a response, I don't see how butterflies and trees provides a good example.

Comment: @whuber: good catch; I suppose comparing the _logs_ of weights might correct for this (assuming variation and measurement noise are geometric).

Comment: I'm just curious, I noticed a recent paper Jovanelly and Lane (2012) attempted to do a paired T-test with a sample size of 1 for both means. I was under the impression this was a poor idea. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: A link to the paper, and perhaps a brief explanation of the context would be good.

Comment: @naught101  I wonder if Curious means this one: http://benthamscience.com/open/togeoj/articles/V006/65TOGEOJ.htm

Comment: This question: [Is there a minimum sample size required for the t-test to be valid?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/) may also be of interest to readers of this thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With such a small sample size the normality assumption is rather important. You may consider the Wilcoxon signed rank test if you think this assumption is faulty.

If the population is normally distributed, there is no minimum sample size. If the mean difference is small relative to the population variance, then you will have very little power as well. However, it is possible to get good power even with a very small sample size.

As an example suppose your pairwise differences were normally distributed with (unknown) variance $\sigma^{2} = 1$. Below are monte carlo estimates (using 10000 sims) of the power for incrementally larger values $0, .5, 1, ..., 5$ of the mean pairwise differences

```
      Mean Difference  Power
 [1,]             0.0 0.0512
 [2,]             0.5 0.1097
 [3,]             1.0 0.2934
 [4,]             1.5 0.5250
 [5,]             2.0 0.7467
 [6,]             2.5 0.8975
 [7,]             3.0 0.9648
 [8,]             3.5 0.9925
 [9,]             4.0 0.9976
[10,]             4.5 0.9998
[11,]             5.0 0.9999
```

So we can see that it is possible for the paired $t$-test to still have good power when the mean difference is pretty large in comparison to the variance of the differences (at least 2x as large in this case), even if $n=4$. Please keep in mind that this all goes directly out of the window if the differences are not normally distributed.

You can look at these powers for other values of the mean difference and variance if you like using the R code below (note: the critical value for the $t$-test when $n=4$ using the usual .05 cutoff is 3.182446. The null value to be tested is assumed to be 0).

```
U=seq(0,5,by=.5)
V=U-U
sig=1

for(k in 1:11)
{
   Z=rep(0,10000)
   for(i in 1:10000)
   {
      diffs=rnorm(4,mean=U[k], sd=sig)
      z=(mean(diffs)-0)/(sd(diffs)/sqrt(4))
      Z[i]=z
   }
   V[k] = mean(abs(Z)>3.182446)
}
X=cbind(U,V)
colnames(X)=c("Mean Difference", "Power")
X
```

Comment: In R you can get the same results using the more user friendly `power.t.test`, that gives you flexibility on what you keep fixed. E.g. the example above becomes `for (k in 0:11){cat(sprintf("%f %f\n", k/2,  power.t.test(n=4, delta=k/2, sd=1, type="paired")$power))}`

Comment: I read somewhere that the Wilcoxon test requires a larger sample size `n > 20`. Can you comment on that?

Answer (score 5):

There is no minimum sample size for a t-test. 
But as @shabbychef noted, you will have very little power.

Comment: may have very little power. If the normality assumption holds, the t-test will still be more powerful than the signed rank test, for one. I'd imagine this is also true for various other non-parametric tests. So, it still may be best to use the t-test.

Comment: Technically, wouldn't the minimum sample size be two pairs, since the standard deviation/error would be undefined with only one sample?  R's `t.test` refuses to perform the test with only one sample.

Comment: @macro while the t-test does have a power advantage at the normal, the probability that the data is actually normal will be zero - and it doesn't take terribly big shifts from normality for the t-test to lose the (surprisingly small) power advantage it has at small sample sizes when its assumptions are true. It would be like saying "Why buy insurance - if I drive perfectly, it would be a waste of money"

Comment: @DavidJ.Harris  Yes, of course.

Comment: @Glen_b, I don't understand what ***"the probability that the data is actually normal will be zero"*** is supposed to mean. If it's a statement about how all assumptions are probably wrong, then you can a poke a hole in literally any procedure (including the signed rank test - that still requires a random sample right ;)). Regarding your second point, I would say it depends very heavily on the type of departure from normality. Some departures from normality may actually increase the power of the test. Perhaps you can expand on what you meant, specifically.

Comment: @macro for example, one needs only be working with distributions that look fairly normal but are a bit heavier tailed before the signed rank test has better power than the t. Why would fractionally better power *at* the normal be particularly useful?  The efficiency of the t relative to the signed rank test can be quite low, but the loss of efficiency of the signed rank test against in even the worst cases for it relative to the t is not bad.

Answer (score 5):

*What is the minimum sample size for a paired t-test?*

Generally speaking for the *ordinary* paired t-test, two pairs is the smallest, yielding 1 d.f.

However, if you have some specific criterion you want to satisfy or some specific cirmcumstance you hope to deal with, that may lead to a different answer.  You'd need to be more specific.

*Which assumption should I check for paired t-test?*

Normally*, I'd try to assess all of them, but if you only have 4 pairs, it's just about hopeless to try. You have four pair-differences, from which two d.f. would go to estimating the mean and variance of the differences (the location and scale not mattering for the assumptions), in essence leaving two d.f. to assess changing variance, dependence (in whatever form occur to you to look for, if any) and normality.

*If my data is non-normal, what is an alternative non-parametric test?*

Paired data: Wilcoxon signed rank test; or sign test; or any number of varieties of permutation test or bootstrap test (depending on how you construct your statistic/what exactly you want to test). All of them still have assumptions, of course.

But the t-test is at least reasonably robust to at least mild non-normality of the differences (and its the differences that are supposed to be normal). If the observations are say, mildly right-skew and not very heavy-tailed, the differences may be indistinguishable from normal even at large sample sizes. That said, there's little reason to avoid the signed rank test if non-normality is the main concern, but with 4 pairs, then you're pretty much stuck with a significance level of 12.5%

---

* To clarify, I mean "assess" in a fairly loose sense. I don't necessarily mean "look at my data", since the assumptions are mainly used to get approximately correct type I error rate. "Assess" will include consideration of what the likely situation would be under $H_0$, what kind of impact that might have on type I error rates, and so on. If I was considering power, I might also think about power under other sets of assumptions for $H_1$.