# Can I conduct t-test for this study

Tags: t-test, small-sample

In my study there are only 15 subjects in the intervention group and 15 in the control group. Can I use the relevant **t-test** to analyze each inter group and intra group differences(pre & post). Will it be a problem with this size of small sample. If it is so, can you give me a minimum sample size. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

t-test doesn't have a minimum sample size, in fact it's designed for working with small samples. More details

> [Is there a minimum sample size required for the t-test to be valid?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/is-there-a-minimum-sample-size-required-for-the-t-test-to-be-valid)

Assume that the usual t-test assumptions are satisfied, you can use the test to test for differences.