# Power calculation for non-significant pilot study?

Tags: statistical-power, group-differences

I have performed a pilot study comparing the means of two groups and I've yielded non-significant results. I wish to determine whether increasing the sample size would have produced a significant difference. My means and SD are:

```
Group 1: mean = 0.086
         SD = 0.05524
         ( n = 5)

Group 2: mean = 0.0926
         SD - 0.0509
         (n=4)
```

What is the best formula to use to consider what sample sizes would render these results significant?

Comment: What statistical test did you use? This is important to determine the sample size. Given the observed mean difference and its variability, it is unfortunately no surprise to arrive at a non-significant result with these group sizes.

Comment: Hi. I performed an unpaired t-test

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/is-there-a-minimum-sample-size-required-for-the-t-test-to-be-valid