# Resampling for comparative purposes

Tags: small-sample, resampling

I'm here with a question concerning resampling. My issue: I measured the stature of an individual and found him markedly tall when compared with other eight subject from the same population. However, I realize that eight is quite a low sample size for making such comparison. I was therefore wondering if I could bypass this problem by means of some resampling. I searched online and found some information about Monte Carlo methods. However, I am rather statistically naive. Could anybody provide me with some suggestion and, possibly, with a strategy to approach this problem in R?

Comment: With small samples Bayesian approach often is a good way to go, e.g. http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/10/tiny-data-and-the-socks-of-karl-broman/

Comment: You also could be interested in this thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/is-there-a-minimum-sample-size-required-for-the-t-test-to-be-valid