# How do we determine if the true population distribution has a finite mean and/or variance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test

Some distributions do not have finite/defined mean/variance: [How can a distribution have infinite mean and variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91512/how-can-a-distribution-have-infinite-mean-and-variance)

Is there a way to determine from your sample if the population distribution has undefined mean or variance?  Both sample means and sample variances obviously always exist. Would it be using a series of Chi-square goodness of fit tests for common distributions without mean/variance?

Knowing if the population has defined mean/variance would impact your ability to draw conclusions using typical parametric statistical tests.